# orphan removal is deleting all previous records when I persist new data

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I'm using hibernate orphanRemoval to manage deletion of child-records.
For example, there is an entity Fp with child entity Ledger

```
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="fp")
    public Set<Ledger> getLedgers() {
        return this.ledgers;
    }
```

Normally **Fp** gets the *set* of ledgers which are edited and if a record is no longer required its just removed from the *set* and it will be deleted from database when **Fp** is persisted.

There is another *'side-effect'* though to this approach, when I want to add new records without necessarily bothering with previous data. All previous data gets deleted.

I create a new *set* of Ledgers and add the set to **Fp**  then save **Fp**

```
LinkedHashSet<Ledger> genLedgerAccSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

Ledger expenseLedger = new Ledger();
expenseLedger.setChartaccountByAccCode(accCode);
expenseLedger.setCreateDate(selectedFp.getYearEnd());
expenseLedger.setCurrency(defaultCurr);                         
expenseLedger.setTxnDate(new Date());
expenseLedger.setFp(fp);                                    
expenseLedger.setDebitAmt(0);
expenseLedger.setCreditAmt(expBalDiff);                                  
genLedgerAccSet.add(expenseLedger);

Ledger expenseLedger2 = new Ledger();
expenseLedger2.setChartaccountByAccCode(accCode2);
expenseLedger2.setCreateDate(selectedFp.getYearEnd());
expenseLedger2.setCurrency(defaultCurr);                         
expenseLedger2.setTxnDate(new Date());
expenseLedger2.setFp(fp);                                    
expenseLedger2.setDebitAmt(0);
expenseLedger2.setCreditAmt(expBalDiff);                                  
genLedgerAccSet.add(expenseLedger2);

fp.setLedgers(genLedgerAccSet);
financialperiodService.update(fp);
//the service implements a method from DAO to merge
final T savedEntity = (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
```

My guess is the new set replaces the old set even though I have not fetched it.
I'm using Hibernate *4.2.4.Final*

Is there a better way add more data to the child-records of *Fp* without ending up deleting all previous records

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting Ledgers in **Fp** object, that's why you delete the child. You need to get the Ledgers from the **Fp** object and then save the new one.

Getting reference to the ledgers:

```
Set<Ledger> genLedgerAccSet = fp.getLedgers();
```

creating the new Ledger:

```
Ledger expenseLedger = new Ledger();
expenseLedger.setChartaccountByAccCode(accCode);
expenseLedger.setCreateDate(selectedFp.getYearEnd());
expenseLedger.setCurrency(defaultCurr);                         
expenseLedger.setTxnDate(new Date());
expenseLedger.setFp(fp);                                    
expenseLedger.setDebitAmt(0);
expenseLedger.setCreditAmt(expBalDiff);                                  

genLedgerAccSet.add(expenseLedger);

expenseLedgerService.save(expenseLedger);
```

I guess **expenseLedgerService** is where you save the Ledger.

Comment: Hi, I'm adding multiple ledgers hence why I use the **Fp** set.
I'm trying to avoid fetching the Fp ledgers first then adding the new ones to it before saving since this would become a performance hindrance as it would fetch the entire table (which is huge). If I have to save using **expenseLedgerService** that means looping thorough the new ledgers saving one at a time

Comment: Since you have set FetchType.LAZY your Set will not be loaded, it will be proxied. You must get the Ledgers and add them to the the Set. If you need to save several Ledgers use batch insert.